# Mixed Loopback/Interface UDP request

Tags: network-interface, route, podman, pi-hole

I'm not sure if this is the most correct spot for this question, if not please let me know and I'll move it.

This is my set up:
pihole running in a rootless podman container using slirp4netns.

The pihole service is running on port 53 inside the container. The container is mapping port 3953 from the host to port 53. I use nftables rules and got all of that working.

This is what works (pihole running on HostA-10.10.10.5):

```
HostB --DNS (UDP/TCP:10.10.10.5:3953)--> HostA:3953 --> Container = valid response
HostA --DNS (UDP/TCP:10.10.10.5:3953)--> HostA:3953 --> Container = valid response
HostA --DNS (TCP:127.0.0.1:3953)--> HostA:3953 --> Container = valid response
HostA --DNS (UDP:127.0.0.1:3953)--> HostA:3953 --> Container = timed out
Container -- DNS (UDP:127.0.0.1:53) --> valid response.
```

If I exec into the container and run tcpdump, I can see the UDP requests come in for all of the request, but the requests from HostA to 127.0.0.1 don't get a response.
This is my tcpdump:

```
#Internal To Container: success
01:04:18.425902 lo    In  IP 127.0.0.1.60839 > 127.0.0.1.53: 57697 [1au] A? pihole.home. (52)
01:04:18.426008 lo    In  IP 127.0.0.1.53 > 127.0.0.1.60839: 57697* 1/0/1 A 10.10.10.5 (52)
```

```
#External to Host: (from HostB): success
01:04:35.044972 tap0  In  IP 10.10.10.6.55428 > 10.0.2.100.53: 63205+ [1au] A? pihole.home. (52)
01:04:35.045154 tap0  Out IP 10.0.2.100.53 > 10.10.10.6.55428: 63205* 1/0/1 A 10.10.10.5 (56)
```

```
#Host loopback (hostA 127.0.0.1): Failed.
01:04:23.666449 tap0  In  IP 127.0.0.1.34179 > 10.0.2.100.53: 27771+ [1au] A? pihole.home. (52)
01:04:28.689778 tap0  In  IP 127.0.0.1.50000 > 10.0.2.100.53: 27771+ [1au] A? pihole.home. (52)
```

And I don't see the log in pihole which makes me wonder if it gets through.

What I did think was interesting was the interface on the HostA loopback was tap0, but IP 127.0.0.1.  Which makes me think it's something weird with routes?

This these are my interfaces in the container (output of: `ip -br a`):

```
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8
tap0             UNKNOWN        10.0.2.100/24
```

This is my 'local' route table:
(`# ip ro sh table local`):

```
local 10.0.2.100 dev tap0 proto kernel scope host src 10.0.2.100 
broadcast 10.0.2.255 dev tap0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.100 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1
```

This is my 'main' route table:
(# `ip ro sh table main`)

```
default via 10.0.2.2 dev tap0 
10.0.2.0/24 dev tap0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.100
```

Which has me wondering if because the request is coming in to 127.0.0.1, but on the tap0 interface, instead of loopback, stuff is broken.

Is this something I can fix with the route table on the container? Or is there another way to fix this?